# Прошу помочь со слайдером

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation, слайдер

Прошу подсказать, я работаю сейчас со css grid и не могу додуматься как сделать слайдер чтобы двигался и исчезал первые

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код на всякий случай Прошу помочь, спасибо

```css
.brands-menu {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.brands-menu .brands-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.brands-menu .brands-wrap .brands-item {
  width: 50%;
  filter: contrast(0%);
}

.brands-menu .brands-item:hover {
  filter: contrast(100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="brands my-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brands-menu">
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/artel.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/beko.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/lg.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/samsung.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/tefal.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <img src="{% static 'img/huawei-logo.png' %}" alt="" class="brands-item">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Прошу подсказать, я работаю сейчас со css grid и не могу додуматься
>   как сделать слайдер чтобы двигался и исчезал первые 
> вот код на
>   всякий случай Прошу помочь*

Судя по Вашему приведенному коду, а в нём нет ровным счетом ничего, здесь не помогать нужно, а создавать. Учитывая полное отсутствие каких-либо Ваших попыток, на основе Вашего же кода приведу Вам самый простой вариант слайдера (хотя очень трудно назвать его слайдером) с использованием CSS анимации и правила `@keyframes`. И в этом нам поможет свойство `transform`. Вот пример такой реализации:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.brands-menu {
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.slide {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  animation: slideshow 8s linear infinite;
}

.slide img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.brands-menu .brands-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.brands-menu .brands-wrap .brands-item {
  width: 50%;
  filter: contrast(100%);
}

.brands-menu .brands-item:hover {
  filter: contrast(0%);
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="brands my-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brands-menu">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://cs6.pikabu.ru/avatars/1702/v1702473-2119104813.jpg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1644362/img_id6708540596632725593.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://vapemap.ru/uploads/prod/100/prod_574d742a460b0.jpeg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1704682/img_id2942505827516921695.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1704682/img_id2942505827516921695.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://grif.ua/files/news/grif_rus/1342864918.jpg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://cs6.pikabu.ru/avatars/1702/v1702473-2119104813.jpg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1644362/img_id6708540596632725593.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://vapemap.ru/uploads/prod/100/prod_574d742a460b0.jpeg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1704682/img_id2942505827516921695.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/1704682/img_id2942505827516921695.jpeg/2hq" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
        <div class="brands-wrap">
          <img src="https://grif.ua/files/news/grif_rus/1342864918.jpg" alt="" class="brands-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему создали два дива .slide?